# Only show 3 first characters of months from Input type Month

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm using the input type "Month" and is showing fine the month in this format: `January 2021`, so besides that, I want to achieve something else just to show the first three characters, for example: `Jan` `Feb` `Oct`, is there any attribute or way to do it?

Or lastly a library that offers that (but I want to avoid this)

My Input:

```html
  <input type="month" value="full-date-here" />
```

The problem here is because I have full time data, and the input formats it to Month Year, so that means, I can't touch the value itself, the format somehow?

Comment: Can you show what code you've prepared yourself to solve the issue, please?

Comment: Can't you just take the left 3 characters? e.g `yourValue.substring(0, 3)`.

Comment: it's surprising to me that you have the month name instead of the number.. anyway it would be as easy as having a map binding each expected month to the month representation you are wishing to show. Anyway you were pretty vague about everything... do you want to get that value in js var? you want that value to be posted like that in your form to be received server side? how is your current html and how do you process that value so far?

Comment: Please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/month what is displayed does not necessarily match the actual input's `value`. The *content* previewed in the input is relative to the user's locale (and the browser that's used).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

May as well post as an answer, but can't you just return the first 3 letters (you can probably apply a formatter instead of this):

`yourValue.substring(0, 3);`. You might need to call `toString()` first.

Comment: But how can you do that, I do have full date format, and the input is formating that way, so I'm asking if we can use an exiting attribute or somehow manipulate the display, not the format itself.